# Deleting repeated word pairs in opposite order

Tags: linux, bash, awk, while-loop

I have a file like this example:

```
cat dog
mouse cat
dog cat
dog mouse
```

What I want is to remove those lines that contains the same words   but in the opposite order, in this case I want "cat dog" but not "dog cat". In the real file I have a great number of pair of words (interactions) and I want to delete redundancies (I am working with unidirectional interactions). Therefore, I want this as a result:

```
cat dog
mouse cat
dog mouse
```

I tried this but it does not return any result:

```
cat file | while read f1 f2; do awk -F" " '($1==$f2) && ($2==$f1)' file; done
```

In this code I only want to find repeated pairs. To delete repetitions I would do something like this:

```
cat file | while read f1 f2; do awk -F" " '($1!=$f2) && ($2!=$f1)' file; done
```

Comment: *I want "cat dog" but not "dog cat"* Why not the other way around?

Comment: It doesn't matter, in fact. I want "cat dog" or "dog cat" but not the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common, idiomatic solution:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
cat dog
mouse cat
dog mouse
```

Comment: [awk remove duplicates seen site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+seen+duplicates+site%3Astackoverflow.com). I fail to see the value of the question and the answers given it has been asked and answered many times, but I am not an expert. I am surprised the several hundred potential duplicates don't yield an answer.

Comment: When someone posts an awk question I have 2 choices: 1) search the archives to see if a similar question has been asked previously and, if so, whether or not any of the answers provided to that question is the actual correct answer and, if so but the correct answer is not the accepted answer (frequent!) decide if I really want to mark this question as a duplicate of that one which means I'm essentially directing people to the wrong answer or 2) post the correct solution. Option 2 is far easier for me and if option 1 is hard for me, I can only imagine how hard it is for beginners.

Comment: As I said in the other post, here's the underlying problem: [Please incentivize duplicate finding when gold badge closes as dup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365253/608639). It is simple economics. It is more profitable to provide an answer rather than do the work. And that teaches the OP that it is profitable to ask the question rather than do the work. In the bigger picture it makes the site fill up with useless junk. It is death by 1000 cuts. And it is why there are hundreds of similar questions.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with profit and everything to do with time. I have time to post a trivial correct solution. I do not have time to search the site for that same solution existing as the accepted answer in some other question. So given how much time I'm willing to spend on SO my choices are to answer or to ignore the question and IMHO answering it is more helpful than ignoring it so that's usually what I choose to do. If someone else has time to go searching the archives for the same solution and closing the question as a dup, more power to them.

Comment: Interesting you feel economic models do not apply. When these junk questions are reduced to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), they are simply *"how do I use {sed|awk|bash}"* questions. Those questions are simply *"how do I use <some command>"*, and they are more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). So if you don't have the time to close as a duplicate then close it as off-topic which takes none of your time.

Comment: Economic models only apply if people care about the currency involved. It'd be pretty difficult to care about value-less points on some web site. If we were talking about dollars or euros or something then I would probably care. The questions I answer are not off topic at all and closing them as such would help no-one and I'd like to think most people participate on SO to help people, not to gather meaningless bundles of points. Do what you like, though - I'm good with my approach, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{b[$1,$2]} !($2,$1) in b' Input_file
```

Comment: Bash returns an error: 'syntax error at or near ,'.

Comment: Try with an extra set of parens like so:  `'{b[$1,$2]} !(($2,$1) in b)'`

Comment: @jas I delete my own answer since you where right about the hashtable. +1 for this one.

Comment: @Swimmingbird, could you please do let me know reason for removing correct answer for this one? I could try to improve this one then?

Comment: The other answer takes less time although in fact, the two work fine.